# Proper way to declare and assign typedef structure variables

Tags: c, embedded

I'm trying to execute the following embedded C program on OnlineGDB tool to test before actually implementing it.

Here is the code

```
typedef struct
{
    int age;
    float hight;
}student;


int main()
{
    student s1;
    s1.age = 16;
    s1.hight = 5.7;
    
    student s2[] = {.age = 10; .hight = 4.8};
    
    printf("age of the student is %d\n", s1.age);
    printf("hight of the student is %f\n", s1.hight);
    
    printf("age of the student is %d\n", s2.age);
    printf("hight of the student is %f\n", s2.hight);
}
```

I would like to know the concept and if you can suggest a link to learn that would be great as well.

error it displaying was

```
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:24:21: error: field name not in record or union initializer
   24 |     student s2[] = {.age = 10; .hight = 4.8};
      |                     ^
main.c:24:21: note: (near initialization for ‘s2’)
main.c:24:30: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘;’ token
   24 |     student s2[] = {.age = 10; .hight = 4.8};
      |                    ~         ^
main.c:29:44: error: ‘(student *)&s2’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   29 |     printf("age of the student is %d\n", s2.age);
      |                                            ^
      |                                            ->
main.c:30:46: error: ‘(student *)&s2’ is a pointer; did you mean to use ‘->’?
   30 |     printf("hight of the student is %f\n", s2.hight);
      |                                              ^
      |                                              ->
```

Comment: `student s2[] = ...` defines `s2` as an *array* of `student` structures. Considering your use of `s2` drop the `[]` part: `student s2 = ...;`.

Comment: `student s2 = {.age = 10, .hight = 4.8};`

Comment: The field separator in a structure initialization list is the **comma**.

Comment: You're supposed to separate the variables inside of your curly brackets, with a _comma_, not a semicolon. Also, according to your errors, you have a struct initialized as a pointer, to access those members, you need to use _->_ instead of a dot

Comment: Is `s2` supposed to be an array of students, or should it be one student object?

Comment: `student s2[] = { { .age = 10, .hight = 10 }, { .age = 11, .hight = 9 }, … };`

Comment: Incidentally, "height" normally has an 'e' in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
student s2 = {.age = 10, .hight = 4.8};
student *s1 = &(student){.age = 10, .hight = 4.8};

student s3[] = { {.age = 10, .hight = 4.8}, 
                 {.age = 11, .hight = 4.4} };

student *s4[] = { &(student){.age = 10, .hight = 4.8}, 
                  &(student){.age = 11, .hight = 4.4} };
```